# How to change MySQL JS> to only MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, mysql-shell

I did custom installation for MYSQL and only included MySQL shell, server, and python connector but I don't know from where Java script came from and because of that I can't connect python and Mysql.

[image]

Please help

Comment: You can switch the execution mode with `\sql` or `\py`, see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-shell/8.0/en/mysql-shell-commands.html

Comment: Can't I make it permanent?

Comment: Yes, set the `defaultMode` setting, see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-shell/8.0/en/mysql-shell-configuring-options.html

Comment: @Progman can you show how the setting of defaultmode works?

Comment: @Timo It is explained in https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-shell/8.0/en/mysql-shell-configuring-options.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just switch the execution mode to sql in the shell:

```
\sql
```

Comment: How would a JS command - Select from - look like in the Mysql JS shell?

Answer (score -1):

[1. write  " \sql " (this will convert  SQL-JS to sql ]
2. write as shown in the image

> \sql
> \connect root localhost